# Error with dplyr group_by

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr

This is my dataset

```
N  Pl

10, WO
20, EI
10, WO
20, WO
30, EI
```

My expected output is

```
N   Pl
10,  2
20,  1
30,  1
```

So, basically, I am counting number of pl with each value at N

I am trying dplyr. I know probably this can also be done with aggregate() but I am not sure how to do with that. So in dplyr I am running this statement and getting the following error

Statement:

```
Diff %>% group_by(N) %>% summarise(pl=count(pl))
```

Here `Diff` is my table name

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

I am not sure how to do that. Any help will be appreciated. Also I have only basic knowledge of R

Comment: even if you would count "unique" occurences, the desired result would be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `Diff %>% group_by(N) %>% summarise(pl= n_distinct(pl))`?

Comment: Try running: Diff$N <- as.factor(Diff$N)

Comment: Your expected output (may be wrong), but we can get using `base R`  `d1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(Diff));d2 <- data.frame(N= rownames(d1), Pl= do.call(pmax,d1))`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your desired output is wrong, try:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(N=c(10,20,10,20,30), Pl=c("WO","EI","WO","WO","EI"))
group <- group_by(df, N)
result <- as.data.frame(summarise(group, Pl = n_distinct(Pl)))
result

   N Pl
1 10  1
2 20  2
3 30  1

# the data.table way
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Pl=uniqueN(Pl)), by= N]
```