# Hierarchical data and descriptives

Tags: r, statistics, hierarchical-data

I have problem handling a hierarchical data structure to obtain simple descriptive statistics; for every level 1 observation, I have several (but not the same number) level 2 observations, such as:

```
Level 1  Level2  x    y    z      k
```

---

```
   1        a   0.12  1  debt     0
   1        b   0.08  1  debt     0
   1        c   0.22  1  debt     0
   2        d   0.32  0  credit   1
   2        e   0.17  0  credit   1
   3        f   0.20  1  credit   1
   3        g   0.11  1  credit   1
   3        h   0.05  1  credit   1
   3        i   0.01  1  credit   1
```

While some variables depends on level 2 (x) others (y,z,k) depends on level 1. If How can I obtain descriptive statistics - such as `table(k)` - grouped for level 1 rather than level 2?

Ex. `table(k)` yields 6 in this particular case, but I would like it to yield 2, such as the number of clusters at level 1 when k=1, something like `table(k ~ study)`

Thank you in advance for your help

Marco

Comment: dplyr package has a group_by() function that can be used here: `k %>% group_by(Level 1) %>% summarise(COUNTS = n(), SUM = sum(x))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It yields `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Comment: Did you install and load the library `dplyr`? Also, the function is '`group_by()`.  `group_by_()` is probably not what you want .

Comment: Yes, it is loaded but it seems that both functions cannot handle numeric values such as the dummy k

Comment: Telling me without showing me doesn't help - post your code so I can help you better. It may be a problem with your output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895876/error-with-dplyr-group-by

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(Level1 = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                 Level2 = letters[1:9],
                 x = c(0.12,0.08,0.22,0.32,0.17,0.20,0.11,0.05,0.01),
                 y = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                 z = c(rep("debt",4),rep("credit",5)),
                 k = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1))

df %>% 
  count(Level1, k) 

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: Level1 [?]

  Level1     k     n
   <int> <dbl> <int>
1      1     0     3
2      2     1     3
3      3     1     3
```

Just be sure to read through the help and vignettes for the package before you say "it doesn't work".  Chances are it works just fine, you're just using it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm sorry to bother you but this does not yield what I was looking for. I most likely expressed myself badly. What I'm looking for is a function that tells me "how many level 1 clusters have k=1?", so in the example above, I'm looking for "2". With dplyr the only thing I managed to get is the whole dataset grouped by level 1

Comment: You're looking at `count()` then.  I've edited my answer.  If you want specific groups in the output then you'd just `filter()` what you want/don't want.